# Show that the set $X=\{x\in \Bbb R^m:|x|=1\}$ is compact.

Tags: real-analysis

I wish to show that the set $X=\{x\in \Bbb R^m:|x|=1\}$ is compact.

First it is obvious that this set is bounded, since all $x\in X$ is bounded by $|x|\lt2$; but I just got stuck on how to show this set is closed.

I know I need to show that every limit point of $X$ is in $X$, but I do not know how to do this explicitly. Any help, please.

Answer (score 9):

$x \to |x|$ is a continuous function.  The inverse image of a closed set under a continuous function is closed.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Show that $\Bbb R^m\setminus X$ is open. For $x\in\Bbb R^m\setminus X$ consider the open ball of radius $\big|\|x\|-1\big|$ centred at $x$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** To show that a set is closed show that it's complement is open.  Let $x \notin X$ be an element in the complement.  We need an open ball around $x$ that doesn't intersect $X$.  Try using $\frac{1}{2}\big||x| - 1\big|$ as the radius of that ball.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, consider a convergent sequence $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ where each $|x_n| = 1$.  Let $x$ be the limit of this sequence.  Since the function $x \to |x|$ is continuous, $\lim_{n \to \infty} |x_n| = |x|$.  But since $|x_n| = 1$ for all $n$, this shows that $|x| = 1$.  This shows that the set is closed.